# How to fade background-image without impacting child elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image, opacity

I was not able to implement the solutions described in some other posts, maybe due to the fact i'm using bootstrap3.

Here is my code :

```css
#ouverture .container {
 position: relative;
 opacity: 0.99;
}

#ouverture .container:before {
 content: "";
    opacity: .1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
 background-image: url(images/index-carrousel/puzzle.jpg);
 background-size: 100px;
 background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
 <section id="ouverture" class="spacer">
  <div class="container">
   <p>Nous avons l'intention de développer une politique d'ouverture
    et de dialogue à l'intérieur de notre parti mais aussi avec les
    autres sensibilités qui s'exprimment à Blonay.</p>
   <p>Cela commence en vous offrant la parole, rejoignez-nous pour
    mettre votre pierre à l'édifice !</p>
   <p>Venez écrire la suite avec nous ...</p>
  </div>
 </section>
```

The background image is not displaying, only the text appear. When I set only the backgroup-image statement, everything is displaying but i don't see my text very well because on the image intensity.

Don't know what is wrong because it seem to me I reproduce the examples found here.

Comment: Just seen that the code is working when I'm setting a width and a height to my container, that I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use height:100% in your `:before` element, any parent containers also must be 100% height. Also, use `display:block`..

http://bootply.com/X2lOd2qspw